# jquery callback and nesting problem

Tags: jquery, callback, nested

I'am really confused and don't know how to get on, probably you can help me :)

I'e made an html-page with an menu which loads external content into an div(all done with jquery and ajax-load).

If i want to add a second function nothing happens and i'am not sure about the nesting, wheather it's right or not.

Here are two function, the first one loads a whole html page, the second loads a external div into a div of the previous loaded file(hope that i described it so that you can understand it :)) (numRand is a random number, not important for the question).

```
function changeMenu(menupunkt) {
$(function(){
    $('#mainContent').fadeOut('fast', function(){ $("#mainContent").load(menupunkt+".html?"+numRand);});
    $('#mainContent').fadeIn('fast');});
    return false;
```

}

Here's the second code:

```
function changeSubMenu(submenupunkt,subdiv) {
    $(function(){
        $('#htmlContainer').fadeOut('fast',function(){ $("#htmlContainer").load(submenupunkt+".html?"+numRand+" div#"+subdiv);});
        $('#htmlContainer').fadeIn('fast');});
        return false;
```

}

I want to combine the two function so that i can call a function:

```
someFunction(menupunkt,submenupunkt,subdiv)
```

This should first load the menupunkt.html and if this action has finished it should load the  div.

if i only want to load a menupunkt and no submenupunkt or subdiv, how can i call the function?

I hope i could explain my question so that you guys can follow it, bit complicated i know :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all

```
$(function() { .... code here .... });
```

is shorthand for

```
$(document).ready(function() { .... code here .... });
```

which is a jQuery way of setting up a function to execute when the DOM has loaded. you are using this inside of your functions `changeMenu` and `changeSubMenu` which is not necessary (*unless* you are executing both functions immediately when a page starts to load, but that would be a *strange* way to set things up).

The `load()` command takes a callback function that will execute when load has completed. For example,

```
$("#mainContent").load(menupunkt+".html?"+numRand, [callback here]);
```

`[callback]` can either be an anonymous function (inline function) or a named function.

Hope this helps